# Use Revision date in calculation

Tags: drupal, view

With `hook_views_post_execute()`, how do you use the `revision_timestamp` or `node_changed` values for finding the difference between dates? Using Devel, there doesn't seem to be a way to target these values. The below is what I get when I try `dpm($view->result)`:

```
node_revision_timestamp (String, 10 characters ) 1475626276
$...[0]->node_revision_timestamp
node_changed (String, 10 characters ) 1475626276
$...[0]->node_changed
```

Comment: Have you as the response of this question indicated, cleared cache as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844148/drupal-hook-views-post-execute-not-getting-called

Comment: yep, it just does not pose as an option with Devel.

Comment: Here is an example of showing the date when it was updated - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73802/how-can-i-show-the-node-create-date